# Hugo - Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource - The resource has been blocked - Host on Github

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, hugo

### Issue:

I am trying to deploy/host my `Hugo` site on GitHub.

The site renders perfectly when I run it locally (`http://localhost:1313/`) using the `hugo server` command, but it does not render correctly when I host it on GitHub.

Initially, I thought the issue was the deployment on GitHub, but then I opened the `index.html` file which is generated by the `hugo` command within the `public` folder and I noticed that it does not work there either. So I assumed there is something wrong with my css connection in the [index.html](https://github.com/MariosKaramanis/marioskaramanis.github.io/blob/master/index.html) file:

```
href=https://username.github.io/assets/css/stylesheet.min.06dcab22093156f8a08872c23ce7ee2a8234185d3c84741f7b0ce0c78df475b8.css
```

but this seems to be the correct link.

### Installation Process and Research Efforts:

In order to create the `hugo` site in the first place, I followed the [quick-start tutorial](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/) and in order to apply the theme of my choice, I followed the official installation process described [here](https://adityatelange.github.io/hugo-PaperMod/posts/papermod/papermod-installation/) by `PaperMod`. Finally, to host it on GitHub, I followed the [recommended instructions](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/).

My [config.yml](https://github.com/MariosKaramanis/marioskaramanis-blog/blob/master/config.yml) file has the recommended structure as the [example file](https://adityatelange.github.io/hugo-PaperMod/posts/papermod/papermod-installation/) presented in the offical repository.

Besides filing an [issue](https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod/issues/89) on the GitHub repository of the theme developer which I didn't get a clear answer except for a correction he pointed out which didn't work, I looked at a couple of articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003005/css-not-working-on-github-pages), [this](https://github.community/t/css-not-being-applied-in-pages/10466/5) and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37097/css-file-from-github-pages-sent-as-text-plain-needs-to-be-text-css) but none of them work.

I am using windows 10 and my Hugo version is `v0.78.2/extended windows/amd64`.

### Update:

I check the console of the html file and I found these three errors:

> (index):1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute
> for resource
> 'https://username.github.io/assets/css/stylesheet.min.5846effdc39e688e1bf07acc7a47123f949ae43a8b0e776fa1a2a626406cc602.css'
> with computed SHA-256 integrity
> 'J6YEe5hjKuk/TENUR7jEMr6VNR4lwN8iVpSGj1g8MU4='. The resource has been
> blocked.

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

> DevTools
> failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Workaround:

I replaced:

`integrity="J6YEe5hjKuk/TENUR7jEMr6VNR4lwN8iVpSGj1g8MU4="`

with:

`integrity=""`

in the css tag of **every single** `index.html` file.

This worked, although I found a solution to do this automatically and skip the error in the first place.

### Solution(!) - Update:

It looks like the `head.html` file under the `assets` folder has the following structure:

```
 <!-- Styles --> 
 {{- $stylesheet := (resources.Match "css/*.css") | resources.Concat "assets/css/stylesheet.css" | minify | fingerprint -}} 
 <link href="{{ $stylesheet.Permalink }}" integrity="{{ $stylesheet.Data.Integrity }}" rel="preload stylesheet" 
     as="style">
```

I replaced `integrity="{{ $stylesheet.Data.Integrity }}"` with `integrity=""` and it worked! It automatically generates `index.html` files that are built with empty `integrity` and as a result there is no error and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to @Samuel Three's answer, I started to look more closely at my Cloudflare configuration.

I discovered that I had Cloudflare's "Auto Minify" feature turned on (under Speed / Optimisation) for JavaScript and CSS. Disabling those (and flushing the Cloudflare cache once) fixed the issue for me, and I was able to leave Cloudflare's cache enabled from that point on.

[image]

Of course, if Cloudflare modify the JS or CSS files in any way, the computed SHA integrity will no longer be correct.

Comment: This is indeed correct, I wonder why CF alters the integrity in the first place....

Comment: I didn't want to ignore integrity completely - that sounds like a bad idea. this was the solution to my specific setup and worked instantly.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else having the same issue with the integrity, adding the following code to my `config.yml` file solved the problem.

```
params:
    assets:
        disableFingerprinting: true
```

Comment: This worked great. With toml it's `params.assets.disableFingerprinting = true`. Wondering if there's a safer yet simple solution though

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution if you are using Cloudflare as the DNS for you domain.

Just clean the Cloudflare CDN cache or turn off it to prevent it happening again.

https://github.com/lxndrblz/anatole/issues/114#issuecomment-828750909

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the integrity completely will, of course, solve this (and we certainly don't want any other processes to modify the file on the fly later - turn that off in Cloudflare if you have it enabled in Speed > Optimization > Auto Minify, for example).

However, I hit this problem because my `fingerprint` wasn't **last** in the chain of resource events that modify the content. For example, this was my problem:

```html
...
{{ $css = $css | fingerprint "sha256" }}
{{ $css = $css | resources.PostCSS }}
{{ $css = $css | resources.PostProcess }}
...
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ $css.RelPermalink }}"
  integrity="{{ $css.Data.Integrity }}"
  media="screen"
/>
```

But this now works perfectly:

```html
...
{{ $css = $css | resources.PostCSS }}
{{ $css = $css | fingerprint "sha256" }}
{{ $css = $css | resources.PostProcess }}
...
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ $css.RelPermalink }}"
  integrity="{{ $css.Data.Integrity }}"
  media="screen"
/>
```

Hope this helps anyone else that hits this gotcha.